# Convert a string made from array toString() back to Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I converted an array to a string and added it to a TextArea. The user edited the TextArea and I need to now update the array by calling in the same string of data I first produced. How would you do this?

The string which I have produced and need to convert back to an array is:

```
{"color":"red","x":218,"y":-11,"width":60,"height":60},{"color":"blue","cx":114,"cy":83,"radius":30}
```

I tried to use the JSON Parser `JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: an array of object ?

Comment: `JSON.parse('[' + text + ']')`?

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Comment: If you had used `text = JSON.stringify(array)` originally then you wouldn't need the workaround (you would be able to simply do `JSON.parse(text)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format your string:

```js
const text = '{"color":"red","x":218,"y":-11,"width":60,"height":60},{"color":"blue","cx":114,"cy":83,"radius":30}'

console.log(JSON.parse(`[ ${text}]`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to format your string as an array in JSON format. You can do that like so:

```
JSON.parse('[' + text + ']')
```

Answer (score 1):

The Below code should work:

```
var text_string = '{"color":"red","x":218,"y":-11,"width":60,"height":60},{"color":"blue","cx":114,"cy":83,"radius":30}';
console.log(JSON.parse(`[${text_string}]`));
```